# Using JVisualVM to examine source of "retained" objects (aka memory leaks)

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jvisualvm

I have a network server app that receives messages in an in-memory queue that are first received on a tcp socket. The messages are then processed and ***supposedly*** discarded.

The queue (just a `java.util.concurrent.ArrayBlockingQueue`) is consistently in a 1 to 2 message size: there is no backup or reference holding there.

Otherwise - there are no in-memory maps, lists, buffers, etc of the messages: they are processed then discarded.So it is unclear to me where to look.

here is a glimpse of the *retained* memory from the `jvisualvm`:  we can see that **96%** of the heap memory is within these `byte[]` arrays. So .. fix ***that*** and the app should be flying again.

[image]

Given I have pored through the code - *does jvisualvm have a means to "drill down" on those byte arrays to see who is holding references to them?*

**Update: from suggestion by @VinceEmigh here is the "Record Allocation stack traces" location:

[image]

Comment: VisualVM has a "Show allocation stack trace" feature. Sadly, I [couldn't get the dang thing to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34052961/prevent-program-from-crashing-when-showing-allocation-stack-traces)..

Comment: Hi Vince - thanks - where is this `show allocation stack trace` feature?

Comment: Go to the profiler tab and run the memory profiler. When you see the type, right click it and you should see "*Take snapshot and show allocation stack trace*" (may need to enable it via options, don't remember - been using JMC ever since). Check out my post for a GIF showing how to do it. If it's an option, I *highly* recommend using JMC