# Application is crashing when record allocation stacktraces option is selected in VisualVM memory profiling

Tags: java, memory-leaks, visualvm, memory-profiling

Application is crashing when "record allocation stack traces" option is selected in VisualVM memory profiling.

I am using VisualVM available as part of JDK 1.8

As per below link VisualVM in JDK 1.8 has issue and we need to use the one available in JDK 1.7. However the application I am profiling is using JDK 1.8 so this solution does not work.

[Prevent program from crashing when showing allocation stack traces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34052961/prevent-program-from-crashing-when-showing-allocation-stack-traces)

Can you please suggest other options which can provide the traces of memory allocation where ever there are leaks.

Please note that I don't have permissions on the system to install applications. so I need some thing which can be run with out installing.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please try to use VisualVM 1.4.1 from http://visualvm.io ? Also make sure that JDK 8u172 or newer is used for profiled application.